# Templatize enum class operators

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to create a flags bitfield using C++11 enum classes. I'm looking for a way to templatize the operators' return types so they can be used as in code below:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Flags {
        one = 1,
        two = 1 << 1,
        three = 1 << 2,
        four = 1 << 3
};

#define _CONVERT(_operator) \
static_cast<T>(static_cast<int>(lhs) _operator static_cast<int>(rhs))

template <typename T>
T operator & (const Flags& lhs, const Flags& rhs) {
        return _CONVERT(&);
}

template <typename T>
T operator | (const Flags& lhs, const Flags& rhs) {
        return _CONVERT(|);
}

#undef _convert


int main()
{
        Flags flag = Flags::one | Flags::two | Flags::three;

        if (flag & Flags::two)
                std::cout << "Flag has two" << std::endl;

        if (flag & Flags::four)
                std::cout << "Flag has four" << std::endl;

        std::cout << static_cast<int>(flag) << std::endl;
}
```

However, there are several problems:

- `Flags flag = Flags::one | Flags::two | Flags::three;` can't deduce type to be `Flags`
- `if (flag & Flags::four)` can't deduce type to be `bool`

I'm new to templates and am kinda lost when it comes to template deduction mechanisms. Also, i tried to create create conversion operator

```
operator bool(const Flags& flag)
```

but with no result.

Comment: when you `|` `one` `two` and `three` what flag do you want the result to map to ?(currently it doesn't map to any value in that enum!)

Comment: Templating operator on return type would allow to call it only that way: `Flags::one.operator<int>&(Flags::two)`... you probably just want `Flags operator & (Flags, Flags)`.

Comment: @Nim `Flags` is `int` type internally, my idea is for it to be able to hold multiple values without explicitly defining them.

Comment: I personally have switched away from enums as direct representation of multiple-choice flags. Have you considered using a `std::bitset` with an enum as an index into the bitset? By doing so you can get the best of both scoped and unscoped enums in the sense that it doesn't decay to the underlying type and not needing to define `operator|` and `operator&`. In my opinion it also leads to easier to read code without sacrificing any performance.

Answer (score 9):

First create a helper template:

```
template<class E>
struct bool_or_enum{
  E e;
  explicit operator bool()const{return static_cast<bool>(e); }
  operator E() const {return e;}
};
```

Next, create a trait function and type:

```
namespace magic_operators {
  template<class E>
  constexpr std::false_type algebraic_enum(E const volatile&) {return {};}

  template<class E>
  using use_algebra=decltype( algebraic_enum( std::declval<E const volatile&>() ) );
}
```

Now `magic_operators::use_algebra<E>` searches using ADL for `algebraic_enum` overload returning `std::true_type` on `E`.  This permits enabling the magic anywhere. MSVC 2015 lacks sufficient C++11 support to use the above; replace with traits class.

The meat: our operators. Stick them into a namespace and bring them in with `using namespace`:

```
template<class E, std::enable_if_t<magic_operators::use_algebra<E>{}, int> = 0>
bool_or_enum<E> operator&(E const& lhs, E const& rhs){
  using U = std::underlying_type_t<E>; 
  return { E( static_cast<U>(lhs) | static_cast<U>(rhs) ) };
}
```

And similar for `|`.

For `~` and `^` you need a bit mask to remain defined behaviour. Have a traits class `enum_mask<E>` that defaults to `E::bit_mask` or somesuch to get it.

```
template<class E, std::enable_if_t<magic_operators::use_algebra<E>{}, int> = 0>
bool_or_enum<E> operator^(E const& lhs, E const& rhs){
  using U = std::underlying_type_t<E>; 
  return { E( enum_mask<E>{} & (static_cast<U>(lhs) ^ static_cast<U>(rhs) ) ) };
}
template<class E, std::enable_if_t<magic_operators::use_algebra<E>{}, int> = 0>
bool_or_enum<E> operator~(E const& e){
  using U = std::underlying_type_t<E>; 
  return { E( enum_mask<E>{} & (~static_cast<U>(e)) ) };
}
```

This is tricky due to standards requirements on out of gamut enums.

`|=` and `&=` isn't hard, but does need to be coded. `=` and `|=` and `&=` etc that support both assignment chaining and implicit bool requires yet more work. I say do not support it.

Oh and mark everything `constexpr` and add `bool_or_enum<E>` overloads to the `operator`s.

The above code is not tested or compiled, but the design works.

---

The end result is:

```
enum class Bob { a=2, b=7, bit_mask = 0x00ff };
constexpr std::true_type algebraic_enum( Bob const& ){ return {}; }
using namespace algebraic_ops;

int main(){
  Bob x=Bob::a;
  x = x | Bob::b;
  if( x &~ Bob::b ){
    std::cout << "cast to bool bitmasking!\n";
  }
}
```

Or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

While the @yakk-adam-nevraumont is nice and works, I preferred not to have to redefine anything for my enum classes, but rather have them to automatically get operators once I include my inline header...

So, I've done something like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace EnumUtils {

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_class() {
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) {
        return !std::is_convertible_v<T, std::underlying_type_t<T>>;
    }
    return false;
}

template <class EnumType>
struct WrapperImpl {
    EnumType e;

    constexpr explicit WrapperImpl(EnumType const& en) : e(en) {}
    constexpr explicit WrapperImpl(std::underlying_type_t<EnumType> const& en)
        : e(static_cast<EnumType>(en)) {}
    constexpr explicit operator bool() const { return static_cast<bool>(e); }
    constexpr operator EnumType() const { return e; }
    constexpr operator std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>() const {
        return std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>(e);
    }
};

template <class EnumType>
using Wrapper =
    std::conditional_t<is_class<EnumType>(), WrapperImpl<EnumType>, void>;
}  // namespace EnumUtils

template <class EnumType, class Wrapped = EnumUtils::Wrapper<EnumType>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<EnumUtils::is_class<EnumType>(), Wrapped> operator&(
    EnumType const& first, EnumType const& second) {
    return static_cast<Wrapped>(static_cast<Wrapped>(first) &
                                static_cast<Wrapped>(second));
}

template <class EnumType, class Wrapped = EnumUtils::Wrapper<EnumType>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<EnumUtils::is_class<EnumType>(), Wrapped> operator|(
    EnumType const& first, EnumType const& second) {
    return static_cast<Wrapped>(static_cast<Wrapped>(first) |
                                static_cast<Wrapped>(second));
}

template <class EnumType, class Wrapped = EnumUtils::Wrapper<EnumType>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<EnumUtils::is_class<EnumType>(), Wrapped> operator^(
    EnumType const& first, EnumType const& second) {
    return static_cast<Wrapped>(static_cast<Wrapped>(first) ^
                                static_cast<Wrapped>(second));
}

template <class EnumType, class Wrapped = EnumUtils::Wrapper<EnumType>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<EnumUtils::is_class<EnumType>(), Wrapped&> operator|=(
    EnumType& first,  //  NOLINT(runtime/references)
    EnumType const& second) {
    first = (first | second);
    return reinterpret_cast<Wrapped&>(first);
}

template <class EnumType, class Wrapped = EnumUtils::Wrapper<EnumType>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<EnumUtils::is_class<EnumType>(), Wrapped&> operator&=(
    EnumType& first,  //  NOLINT(runtime/references)
    EnumType const& second) {
    first = (first & second);
    return reinterpret_cast<Wrapped&>(first);
}

template <class EnumType, class Wrapped = EnumUtils::Wrapper<EnumType>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<EnumUtils::is_class<EnumType>(), EnumType> operator~(
    EnumType const& first) {
    return static_cast<EnumType>(~static_cast<Wrapped>(first));
}
```