# C++ all path throught this function will call itself in macro?

Tags: c++, recursion, enums

Hey guys I have written a macro to easy define enum operators and I'm getting

> warning: all path through this function will call itself

I understand that this means the function is recursive, but where?

```
#define DEFINE_BITMASKENUM_OPERATORS(et, ut) \
    constexpr et operator &(const et a, const et b) noexcept { return (et(static_cast<ut>(a) & static_cast<ut>(b))); } \
    constexpr et operator |(const et a, const et b) noexcept { return (et(static_cast<ut>(a) | static_cast<ut>(b))); } \
    constexpr et operator ^(const et a, const et b) noexcept { return (et(static_cast<ut>(a) ^ static_cast<ut>(b))); } \
    constexpr et operator~(const et a) noexcept { return ~(a); } \
    inline et& operator&=(const et& a, const et b) noexcept {  return (reinterpret_cast<et&>((ut&)a &= (ut)b)); } \
    inline et& operator^=(const et& a, const et b) noexcept {  return (reinterpret_cast<et&>((ut&)a ^= (ut)b)); } \
    inline et& operator|=(const et& a, const et b) noexcept {  return (reinterpret_cast<et&>((ut&)a |= (ut)b)); }
```

et is the enum type and ut the underlying type. It would be used like this:

```
enum kRUNTIME_FLAGS : short16
{
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_DEF                                                                          = 0b010,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_NO_RUNTIME_STATISTICS_RECORDING          = 0b0100,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ENABLE_TERMINAL                          = 0b01000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ENABLE_EDIT_MODE                         = 0b010000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ALLOW_EDIT_MODE_SWITCH                   = 0b0100000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_STOP                                     = 0b01000000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ALLOW_AUTO_STRIDE_FLUSH                  = 0b010000000
};
DEFINE_BITMASKENUM_OPERATORS(kRUNTIME_FLAGS, short16)
```

but where is the function calling itself and how do i fix this?
Its fixed now, for everybody who need something like this, this template version should work i think:

```
template<typename ENUM, typename  ENUM_TYPE = typename std::underlying_type<ENUM>::type>
constexpr ENUM operator&(const  ENUM a, const  ENUM b) noexcept { return (ENUM(static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(a) & static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(b))); }
template<typename ENUM, typename  ENUM_TYPE = typename std::underlying_type<ENUM>::type>
constexpr ENUM operator|(const  ENUM a, const  ENUM b) noexcept { return (ENUM(static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(a) | static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(b))); }
template<typename ENUM, typename  ENUM_TYPE = typename std::underlying_type<ENUM>::type>
constexpr ENUM operator^(const  ENUM a, const  ENUM b) noexcept { return (ENUM(static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(a) ^ static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(b))); }
template<typename ENUM, typename  ENUM_TYPE = typename std::underlying_type<ENUM>::type>
constexpr ENUM operator~(const ENUM a) noexcept { return ENUM(~static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(a)); }
template<typename ENUM, typename  ENUM_TYPE = typename std::underlying_type<ENUM>::type>
inline ENUM& operator&=(const ENUM& a, const ENUM b) noexcept { return (reinterpret_cast<ENUM&>((ENUM_TYPE&)a &= (ENUM_TYPE)b)); }
template<typename ENUM, typename  ENUM_TYPE = typename std::underlying_type<ENUM>::type>
inline ENUM& operator^=(const ENUM& a, const ENUM b) noexcept { return (reinterpret_cast<ENUM&>((ENUM_TYPE&)a ^= (ENUM_TYPE)b)); }
template<typename ENUM, typename  ENUM_TYPE = typename std::underlying_type<ENUM>::type>
inline ENUM& operator|=(const ENUM& a, const ENUM b) noexcept { return (reinterpret_cast<ENUM&>((ENUM_TYPE&)a |= (ENUM_TYPE)b)); }
```

Comment: `constexpr et operator~(const et a) noexcept { return ~(a); }`

Comment: Looks like you forgot the static cast in `constexpr et operator~(const et a) noexcept { return ~(a); }`

Comment: Generally speaking, in c++ you should avoid macros other than include guards and conditional compilation. You should be able to do everything you need here with static methods and templates.

Comment: yeah i know maybe ill implement this later wih templates

Comment: i added a template version

Comment: @Tzalumen I don’t think that’s true here. Until we get metaclasses, there’s no way to do this with just templates in a way that will work. If you write these functions as templates and use SFINAE, [`is_enum_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum), and [`underlying_type_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) to get them to work correctly, [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) won’t find them because they aren’t in the associated set of namespaces for the enum. If that weren’t the case they’d be defined for all enums, which isn’t good.

Comment: @xX_EASYHDLPMCAWPGOD_Xx Your template version shouldn’t work if you have an enum in a different namespace, but I think some compilers will accidentally find and apply it anyway in some circumstances.

Comment: @DanielH The templates should work fine if he uses the correct amount of `Scope::Resolution::Operators`

Comment: These are *overloaded operators*, not regular functions. I’m fairly sure that C++ doesn’t let you use `my_enum_1 EnumOps::& my_enum_2;`, and even if it does that’s not desirable.

Comment: @Tzalumen The best you can do is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40219071/27302), but that either requires `using` the operators into the global namespace from the header file where the enum is defined (and even though they won’t interfere with any class they aren’t enabled for that’s still code smell and I’m not 100% confident there wouldn’t be unwanted consequences even with proper SFINAE) or it requires the person including the enum to also include the operators.

Comment: @DanielH Using macro defines like this is also code smell, so it's really a question of what flavor of stink to get on your code to avoid manually coding operator overloads.

Comment: The template version is working like a charm for me ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
constexpr et operator~(const et a) noexcept { return ~(a); }
```

to

```
constexpr et operator~(const et a) noexcept { return et(~static_cast<ut>(a)); }
```

and it should compile without warnings.

```
#include <cstdint>
#define DEFINE_BITMASKENUM_OPERATORS(et, ut) \
    constexpr et operator &(const et a, const et b) noexcept { return (et(static_cast<ut>(a) & static_cast<ut>(b))); } \
    constexpr et operator |(const et a, const et b) noexcept { return (et(static_cast<ut>(a) | static_cast<ut>(b))); } \
    constexpr et operator ^(const et a, const et b) noexcept { return (et(static_cast<ut>(a) ^ static_cast<ut>(b))); } \
    constexpr et operator~(const et a) noexcept { return et(~static_cast<ut>(a)); } \
    inline et& operator&=(const et& a, const et b) noexcept {  return (reinterpret_cast<et&>((ut&)a &= (ut)b)); } \
    inline et& operator^=(const et& a, const et b) noexcept {  return (reinterpret_cast<et&>((ut&)a ^= (ut)b)); } \
    inline et& operator|=(const et& a, const et b) noexcept {  return (reinterpret_cast<et&>((ut&)a |= (ut)b)); }

enum kRUNTIME_FLAGS : int16_t
{
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_DEF                                                                          = 0b010,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_NO_RUNTIME_STATISTICS_RECORDING          = 0b0100,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ENABLE_TERMINAL                          = 0b01000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ENABLE_EDIT_MODE                         = 0b010000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ALLOW_EDIT_MODE_SWITCH                   = 0b0100000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_STOP                                     = 0b01000000,
    kRUNTIME_FLAGS_ALLOW_AUTO_STRIDE_FLUSH                  = 0b010000000
};
DEFINE_BITMASKENUM_OPERATORS(kRUNTIME_FLAGS, int16_t)
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ORF5iX

Comment: He really ought to be using templates for this.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very very much ;) yeah i forgot the static cast on the bitwise not!