# Opt-in / Customization point for template enum class operators

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I often use enum class for flags like this:

```
enum class MyFlags : uint32_t {
  None  = 0,
  Flag1 = (1 << 0),
  Flag2 = (1 << 1),
  ...
}
```

Now I often want to do operations for combining the flags like this:
`MyFlags::Flag1 | MyFlags::MyFlags2`

So i need an operator overload for this:

```
MyFlags operator|(MyFlags f1, MyFlags f2)
{
   return static_cast<MyFlags>(uint32_t(f1) | uint32_t(f2));
}

// other operators like =|, &, also defined.
```

Since I find myself doing this for various `enum classes` I would like to write a template for this, but only activate the enum classes that are actually using flags (opt-in) so it's not used for all enums.

How can I enable the operator for some selected enums? The following is how far I got:

```
// What other code here to only select this for selected types?
template <typename T> // Concept instead of typename?
T operator|(T f1, T f2)
{
   return static_cast<T>(uint32_t(f1) | uint32_t(f2));
}

// Other .cpp file
// Here I'd like to do opt-in. Is this done with template specialization? std::enable_if? Other?
// What code here to use the above template for MyFlags?
```

As indicated in the comments, I'd like to use concepts if possible. If there are other ways, it would be ok too.

Comment: why do you want other approaches? What others? Whats the actual question? How to write the code with concepts? How to write the code without concepts? Note that questions in comments are easily overlooked, better state the question clearly in the text

Comment: Related (*maybe* even a duplicate): [Templatize enum class operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40218431/10871073)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, thanks for the suggestions. I wanted to write this with concepts since this is the recommended ways of doing templates. I'm no expert on it and wanted to get the *best practices* in this regard, but I wasn't sure it was possible, so asked for alternatives. I got both approaches in the answers below - exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: rather than lengthy comments I made an edit. Rollback or fix as you like.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I'll keep the edit. Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you would make your concept:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept enable_bitops_for = std::is_enum_v<T> && /* ... */;

template <enable_bitops_for T>
constexpr T operator|(T f1, T f2)
{
   return static_cast<T>(std::to_underlying(f1) | std::to_underlying(f2));
}
```

Now the question is how you define your concept so that it's only satisfied for enums you specifically enable it for.

A classic way is template specialization:

```cpp
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool do_enable_bitops_for = false;

template<typename T>
concept enable_bitops_for = std::is_enum_v<T> && do_enable_bitops_for<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;

enum class MyFlags : uint32_t {
  None  = 0,
  Flag1 = (1 << 0),
  Flag2 = (1 << 1),
  ...
};

template<>
inline constexpr bool do_enable_bitops_for<MyFlags> = true;
```

This has some problems if your enum class is defined inside a namespace or a class since you have to leave the namespace or class to specialize.

Another is some sort of tag:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept enable_bitops_for = std::is_enum_v<T> && (T::_enable_bitops == T{});

enum class MyFlags : uint32_t {
  None  = 0,
  Flag1 = (1 << 0),
  Flag2 = (1 << 1),
  ...,
  _enable_bitops = 0
};
```

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept enable_bitops_for = std::is_enum_v<T> && requires {
    { _enable_bitops(T{}) } -> std::same_as<std::true_type>;
};

enum class MyFlags : uint32_t {
  None  = 0,
  Flag1 = (1 << 0),
  Flag2 = (1 << 1),
  ...
}
std::true_type _enable_bitops(MyFlags);
```

Comment: Nice solution with concepts. Regarding the namespace issue, if the template is in the same namespace as the specialization, would this still be an issue?

Comment: @SupAl If your template is `ns1::ns2::templatename`, it must be specialized in `ns1::ns2`, `ns1` or `::` (the global namespace). So if it's in the same namespace it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a trait that defaults to `false` and can be specalized for any enum that should use the custom operator. The operator can then SFINAE on that trait:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template <typename T> struct uses_operator : std::false_type {};


template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<uses_operator<T>::value && std::is_enum<T>::value,T> operator|(const T& f1, const T& f2)
{
   return static_cast<T>(
        static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(f1) | 
        static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(f2));
}

enum class enum1 {A,B};
enum class enum2 {C,D};

template <> struct uses_operator<enum1> : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    enum1::A | enum1::B;  //OK
    enum2::C | enum2::D;  //Error
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bMvr6ebb8)

For other enums that should use the operator you only have to supply a specialization of the trait.

The reason there is no concept in the code is that I am not fluent with concepts, though I am not sure if it would bring any benefit (other than avoiding the somewhat arcane `enable_if`).

Comment: Concepts would improve compile time (no need to instantiate the template only to see it fail - i.e., not SFINAE) and a clearer error message (specific concept is not satisfied).